# Detect the operating system

Tags: system-environment, debian

What is the most Emacs-y way to detect the operating system Emacs is running in?

My intention is to conditionally set up `package` repositories depending on whether they are needed. (If the operating system is one that I know has Emacs packages available, I want to preferentially use those instead.)

I can use hacks like "detect whether `/etc/debian_version` exists", or even parsing its content. But if Emacs already knows how to tell me what operating system is running, I should use that. Does this exist?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT

I just now found the variable `operating-system-release`, which (i.c.w. `system-type`), I guess, comes closest to what you are looking for. However, it might be handy for you to know its value on different operating systems. Maybe readers can help you out in the comments. It seems to be equal to the output of the `uname -r` command, so you could also search the web for its output on different distro's.

I am using Fedora 36 where its value is:

```
"6.0.7-200.fc36.x86_64"
```

END EDIT

As you are referring to `/etc/debian_version, I guess you mean that, in addition to knowing which OS is running, you'd also like to know which (GNU/)linux distribution is being used. The available 'system' variables and functions are described in [this section of the elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Environment.html).

The `system-type` and `system-configuration` variables, will tell you which type of OS is being used. There is no 'system' variable that provides info about the used distribution.

However, on (GNU/)linux, you could probably use the following to obtain a useful alist from `/etc/os-release` (or you could process the file in some other way also of course):

```lisp
(pp
 (with-temp-buffer
   (insert-file-contents-literally "/etc/os-release")
   (replace-string "\"" "")
   (let ((lines (split-string (buffer-string) "\n" t)))
     (mapcar (lambda (l) (split-string l "=")) lines)))
 (pop-to-buffer "*os-release*"))
```

where you can remove the `pp`, which only serves to present a nice view of the result.

Comment: My reading was that `system-type` was the primary need; but between the two of them that should do the trick.  `C-h i g (elisp)System Environment` to read this inside Emacs.

Comment: `system-name` is the machine name.  I'm guessing you meant `system-type`, like @phils mentioned.

Comment: Ah, I see. I only read the values of those variables from [Ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper). Then I did not realize that 'system-name' (which here is 'Fedora') actually showed my hostname (I did not read the variable its doc(string)). So then I guess the second part of the answer is the most relevant/useful part...

Comment: I have updated the answer